# UITableView section not reloading when called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want a section of my table view to reload whenever the ViewWillAppear method is called, I've implemented this like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    reloadRows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Here is the rowforsection method that indicates which content should appear in each tableview section:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"fadk");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PINGAS"];
    [self.tableView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"PINGAS"] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


       // if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 300, 41)];
            UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 120)];
            UIView *paddingView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 0)] autorelease];
            paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];


          //  if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"0");
            [cell addSubview:textField];
            if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
                textField.placeholder = @"Title";
            }
            else{
                textField.placeholder = @"Location";
            }
        }
        else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"1");
            NSDateFormatter *formatter;
            NSString *eSString1;
            NSString *eEString2;
            formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Starts\nEnds";
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            eSString1 = [formatter stringFromDate:eSTime];
            eEString2 = [formatter stringFromDate:eEtime];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", eSString1, eEString2];
            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"2");
            [cell addSubview:textView];

        }

            textField.delegate = self;
            textField.leftView = paddingView;
            textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
            textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
            textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
            textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            textField.tag = 0;
            //playerTextField.delegate = self;

            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
            [textField setEnabled: YES];



            [textField release];

        textView.delegate = self;
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
        textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
        textView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
        textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        textView.tag = 0;



        [textView release];
       // }
    }
    return cell;    
}
```

This works swimmingly the first load, and I after the first calling of viewWillAppear, but after that the section seems to recycle the data from the first load and the second load, and while it still enters the cellforrow section, it no longer goes into the section I call in the viewWIllAppear section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reload should be sandwiched between begin / end updates:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```